# When I kill the app from the background widget get a stop

Tags: android, timer, widget

```
 var service: PendingIntent? = null
            val intentForService = Intent(context!!.applicationContext, NewAppWidget::class.java)
            val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

            val cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"))
            val currentHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
            val currentMinutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
            val currentSeconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)
            val currentMicroSecods = cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)


            if (service == null) {
                service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentForService, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
                val formater = DecimalFormat("00")
                systemTimePast = "${formater.format(currentHour)}:${formater.format(currentMinutes)}:${formater.format(currentSeconds)}:${formater.format(currentMicroSecods.div(10))}"

            }
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.time.time, 1000, service)
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is only one method to run your app  after killing from the background!**

> That method is a notification Access.

There are a few ways in which you can run widgets  after the app closes:

1. Show your app widget on top of the top notification bar.
2. Show your notification class in the background.

If the operating system closes your app then your notification class restart itself.
There are many websites available on the internet which method you code related to it!

*I hope Sir, Your concept will be clear about it.*